# using that login i want to store some values like Name,emailAddress in other file

Tags: python, django

when i try that logic it show only last record of my file means all records are overriding in django.

```
with open('persons.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
                filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                filewriter.writerow(['Name', name],)
                filewriter.writerow(['emailAddress', emailAddress])
                filewriter.writerow(['password', NewcheckPassword])
```

Comment: Perfect English is not required on StackOverflow,or I myself would be pretty lost. But in this case I think your question will remain unclear to practically everybody if you do not find some help with the phrasing. Is there anybody more fluent available to do a little review on your question?

Comment: Otherwise it migth be helpful to give more details. Show examples of input and output. Explain what you expect differently. Show more code. Write more explanation.

Comment: If you have access to the password in a way which allows writing it out to a CSV file you're doing something very very wrong.

Comment: can you please suggest me other way

Comment: can you please suggest me other way